# Postgresql select columns in join query

Tags: postgresql

say that i do inner join in query... the result will give columns from both table.
Is there a way to specify that i want only columns from one of the tables without specifying all columns names manualy?

Comment: Basic SQL questions are off topic on dba.SE.

Comment: You can use `tablename.*` (or `alias.*` if you alias the tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a table alias:

```
select t1.*
from table_1 t1
  join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id1;
```